# Create and store objects in list Python

Tags: python

```
class Prog:

    def __init__(self, name, course, languange):
        self.name = name
        self.course = course
        self.languange = languange

    def show(self):
        print("Name:", self.name, "\nCourse:", self.course, "\nLanguage:", self.languange, "\n")

#Complete code

Students = []
#Create and store the students info (objects) in the list Students
number_of = int(input("Number of students?: "))
#Complete code
loop = 0
while loop < antal:
    print("Name, course language?") #here I want the user to type the name, course and what programming language he/she is studying

print("The following students are now in the system")
#Complete code
```

I want the output to be:

```
Number of students?: 2
Name, course, language?
Alan
P1
Python

Name, course, language?
Jane
P2
Python

The following students are now in the system:
Name : Alan
Course : P1
Language : Python

Name : Jane
Course : P2
Language : Python
```

I can't seem to give `self.name, self.course, self.language` the `input()` value in the list `Students = []`

I did try to `.append`to the list but when I write  `p.Prog(Students)`I get this error message `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'course' and 'languange'`

This is the code I wrote to store values into the list.

```
Students = []
number_of = int(input("Number of students?: "))
loop = 0
while loop < number_of:
    print("Name, course, language?")
    name = input()
    course = input()
    language = input()
    loop += 1

p = Prog(Students)
print("Following students are now in the system.")
p.show()
```

Comment: `Students.append(Prog(name, course, language))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to append to `Students`.

When you call `Prog()`, you have to provide the 3 values that you just input as parameters. It's not clear why you thought the `Students` list would be the proper argument there.

Then when you want to list all the students, you have to loop through the `Students` list.

```
Students = []
number_of = int(input("Number of students?: "))
for _ in range(number_of):
    name = input('Name: ')
    course = input('Course: ')
    language = input('Language: ')
    p = Prog(name, course, language)
    Students.append(p)

print("Following students are now in the system.")
for student in Students:
    student.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and clear answer.

Ill look into this later on tonight

Comment: Works like a charm, a followup question to this, how do I store different values to X number of loops?

Can a user input the first lap be :
Name : A
Course : B
Language : C

And the second lap be:
Name: D
Course: E
Language: F

Do I need to add another loop or can I do this in the same loop?

Comment: Isn't that what this does? If not, I don't understand the question.

Comment: My bad - sorry for the confusion

Thanks again

Comment: I wrote the code and missed to have the append in the while loop